# Maximum subaddresses per account & wallet

Tags: rpc, address

Is there a maximum number of subaddresses you can generate using wallet-rpc?

Can't find this in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

There's no limit on the amount of subaddresses that can be generated. However, note that (i) the default is set to `10000` and (ii) the more subaddresses are generated, the larger the wallet cache will be. Please see as well:

[What is a disposable / sub-address?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3673/what-is-a-disposable-sub-address)

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5vgjs2/subaddresses_and_disposable_addresses/